# Filter field values of nested components in strapi

Tags: graphql, strapi

I'm trying to somehow filter for field values that are set in a component (formerly group). I was assuming my object structure is quite simple, but cannot get it to work.

This is my (simplified) structure taken from the generated graphql schema:

```
type Product {
  name: String!
  description: String
  systemtype: Systemtype
  applicationAreas: [ComponentContentApplicationArea]
  id: ID!
  created_at: DateTime!
  updated_at: DateTime!
}

type ComponentContentApplicationArea {
  rating: Int!
  statement: String!
  applicationareaname: Applicationareaname
  id: ID!
}

type Applicationareaname {
  name: String!
  description: String!
  id: ID!
  created_at: DateTime!
  updated_at: DateTime!
}
```

My GraphQL base query without any filter:

```
query {
  products {
    applicationAreas {
      rating
      applicationareaname{
        name
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Result:

```
{
  "data": {
    "products": [
      {
        "applicationAreas": [
          {
            "rating": 5,
            "applicationareaname": {
              "name": "Area A"
            }
          },
          {
            "rating": 7,
            "applicationareaname": {
              "name": "Area B"
            }
          },
          {
            "rating": 7,
            "applicationareaname": {
              "name": "Area C"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

My understanding is that I can filter for the rating field value this way - but obviously I'm wrong:

```
query {
  products (where: {applicationAreas: {rating: 5}}) {
    applicationAreas {
      rating
      applicationareaname{
        name
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm getting this error when executing the query above:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Your filters contain a field 'applicationAreas.rating' that doesn't appear on your model definition nor it's relations",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "products"
      ],
      "extensions": {
        "code": "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR",
        "exception": {
          "status": 400,
          "stacktrace": [...]
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "data": {
    "products": null
  }
}
```

Any help highly appreciated as I'm totally stuck on this.

Many thanks!

Comment: Did you be able to solve that?

Comment: No, we switched to Directus (https://directus.io) which met our requirements even better than Strapi and seems to be more stable and reliable.

Answer (score 0):

In order to filter data in a component you can use the [advance population feature of the Entity Service API](https://docs-next.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/developer-resources/database-apis-reference/entity-service/populate.html#advanced-populating), like in this example:

```js
strapi.entityService('api::Product.Product').findMany({
  populate: {
    ComponentContentApplicationArea: true,
    repeatableComponent: {
      filters: {
        rating: 5
      },
      populate: true,
    },
  },
});
```